# Display notice for products of specific categories in cart?

Tags: php, magento, cart

I want some help with magento! All i want to do is to display a note or a warning (regarding shipping or a simple note) under the condition that if the cart contains any product lets say from category 4 or 6 or 8 etc..

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    foreach($product->getCategoryIds() as $cat_id){
        if($cat_id == 6||...) {
           ... do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: dosen helps much :-( where do i put this code? i tried placing in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml and also if a product has been assigned to more than one categories may be how do i fetch parent ID using this code and use that instead? thanks

Comment: Getting parent category is not hard you need to load each category and do ->getParentId(). Just make sure parent category Id is greater than 2 as 0 is root and 1 is default.

Comment: you can put this code in a model or helper... and what you can do is inside the if statements: Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->addNotice('your message').